# How to find out the time difference between zookeeper server and curator?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I need to test the modification time for a node and see how "old" this modification date is ? So I would consider it for processing if it's "too old".

So basically I need to compare the current time of the machine running the Apache Curator, with the time of the ZK server running.

To do that, I create a sequential ephemeral node, get it's stat and immediately compare it's creation time with the time I have at the client's side (Curator).

My question: Is there a more out-of-the-box/standard method to figure that out ?

Comment: how about set the current time in your machine to data of zknode ?

Comment: That's what I did, and compared it to the creation time of ZK. I'm asking if there is an out-of-the-box solution for that. Or a more accurate way that tolerates network latency.

Comment: that's not what you did, you have to care the time of server in the operations you mentioned. I don't think there is  an out-of-the-box solution for this in zk. maybe you can give a bigger picture of your question.